# Im getting this error I cant resolve in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, future

```
Future<String> task2() async {
  Duration three = const Duration(seconds: 3);
  String result;

  await Future.delayed(three, () {
    result = 'task 2 data';
  });
  return result;
}
```

> The non nullable local variable 'result' must be assigned before it can be used.

now if i assign it a value on initiation or add a null check, the function just returns that value and not the intended value `task 2 data`

Can someone identify the problem and help me resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need call `then` like this:

```
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)).then((_) {
      result = 'task 2 data';
});
```

or `whenComplete`:

```
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)).whenComplete(() => result = 'task 2 data');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add "?"  with String because it Future type String and also use setState function

```
Future<String?> task2() async {
Duration three = const Duration(seconds: 3);
String? result;
await Future.delayed(three, () {
  setState(() {
    result = 'task 2 data';
  });
});
return result;
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).